# Nmap unable to resolve flags

Tags: command-line, options, nmap

When I type in the command `nmap –Pn –sT -sV –p0-65535 192.168.1.100`, my terminal responds:

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-01-29 11:24 PST
Failed to resolve "–Pn".
Failed to resolve "–sT".
Failed to resolve "–p0-65535".
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.100
Host is up (0.0075s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE    SERVICE VERSION
53/tcp filtered domain

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.73 seconds
```

I'm confused as to why it is failing to resolve the flags. This used to work on my machines; I have a MacBook and am using bash, as well as Kali Linux. I have tried restarting both machines, and it continually fails to resolve flags regardless of which IP address I attempt to scan.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

nmap did not recognize those options because they start with a unicode [EN DASH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) (342 200 223, `–`) instead of a [hyphen or regular dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm) (`-`). As a result, nmap interprets those "options" as names to resolve.